# Differentiate membrane signal from organelles, microscopy image analysis

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to count cells in a microscopy image, and i need to differentiate between the membrane signal and organelles within.

There is only one color, as we are visualizing a protein within the cells using GFP

[image: Typical image]

Right now i am using skimage package (measure, labels). This method kinda works, as it can find connected black regions, and by using the convex of these in together with the bounding box, i can achieve the following (inside: red, membrane: blue):
[image: Found cells and membranes]

I am however having problems with organelles (bright spots inside) that touch the membrane and hence I lose signal from the inside (which then is added to the membrane signal - which is a problem).

Any suggestions for a better method?

```
from skimage import measure
from skimage.segmentation import clear_border
image= ndimage.gaussian_filter(raw_image, sigma=(0.5,0.5), order=0)
median = np.median(image)

mask_inv =np.ma.masked_where(image>median*1.5,image) # was 5 
array = np.zeros(image.shape)
img_contour_inv =np.array(array+mask_inv,dtype=np.float)
mask_inverse_bool = img_contour_inv>0


labels = measure.label(mask_inverse_bool,connectivity=1)

df=measure.regionprops(lables, intensity_image=intensity_image)
```

Followed by some plotting sorting by size and plotting yields image 2

Comment: I don’t think the membrane and nuclei are stained with the same flourophores, are they? You need to use the color information to separate these, then it becomes a trivial problem!

Comment: There are only one color in the image, as we are actually visualizing a protein tagged by GFP - so unfortunately that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

- Find the black spots as you have done in Inside image. Make Inside
  image a black and white image.
- Now inverse the Inside image and multiply it with the raw image. Bright spots will be 
  left behind.
- To get cell contours, you can subtract the bright spots from the raw image.

Another method could be using thresholding to find bright spots.